# How to solve triple integral?

Tags: calculus, multiple-integral

$\int_{-2}^{5} \! \int_{-4}^{5} \! \int_{-4}^{3} \! \frac{1}{5x+8z+80}  \, dx  \, dy  \, dz $

What to do with $\frac{1}{5x+8z+80}$ ? How to make it simplier?

Comment: Do you have to make it simpler? It's just $\frac{1}{ax+b}$ for the first integral. It will be a natural logarithm, and then it starts being more difficult.

Comment: To add to @JSchoone's comment: you're done after the second integral anyway, since the integrand has no $y$-dependence.  Also, we do not *solve* integrals; we solve equations.  We *evaluate* integrals.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang How do you mean that is done after second integral? I will have: $\frac{1}{5}ln(\frac{8z+95}{8z+60})$ and then integral of it will be: $y\frac{1}{5}ln(\frac{8z+95}{8z+60})$.. So it becomes complicated? Or I am making mistake..?

Comment: @AnaMatijanovic You are on the right track.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have

$$\int \dfrac{1}{ax+b}=\dfrac{\ln(ax+b)}{a}+C.$$

Then

$$\int_{-3}^4 \dfrac{dx}{5x+8z+80} = \left. \dfrac{\ln(5x+8z+80)}{5} \right |^{x=3}_{x=-4} = \dfrac{\ln(8z+105)}{5} -\dfrac{\ln(8z+60)}{5}. $$

Then you have

\begin{multline}
\int_{-4}^5 \left(\dfrac{\ln(8z+105)}{5} -\dfrac{\ln(8z+60)}{5} \right)dy = \ln(8z+105) -\ln(8z+60) \\ - \dfrac{1}{4} \left( \dfrac{\ln(8z+105)}{5} -\dfrac{\ln(8z+60)}{5} \right).
\end{multline}

The last integral is

$$ \int_{-2}^5 \left(  \ln(8z+105) -\ln(8z+60)- \dfrac{1}{4} \left( \dfrac{\ln(8z+105)}{5} -\dfrac{\ln(8z+60)}{5} \right) \right)dz,$$

which is very ugly. Again, you have a 'simple form' of this integral

$$ \int \ln(ax+b) \, dx= \dfrac{(ax+b) \ln(ax+b)-ax}{a}. $$

For the first term

\begin{multline}
\int_{-2}^5 \ln(8z+105) \,dz = \dfrac{(40+105)\ln(40+105)-40}{8} \\ - \dfrac{(-16+105)\ln(-16+105)+16}{8}.
\end{multline}

And as you may know, the algebra will be tedious for the remaining three terms.